# Java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: attempt to use the recycled bitmap image android.graphics.Bitmap@5d976e0

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Я создал PagerAdapter в своем приложение, но приложение начинает крашиться при пролистывание адаптера с такой ошибкой:

```
08-06 14:59:08.543 2704-2704/com.secret.cardfocus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.secret.cardfocus, PID: 2704
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@28ebced
                                                                at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1271)
                                                                at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:257)
                                                                at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2443)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Как решить проблему? Вот код адаптера:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] allImages;
//        ImageView imageView;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] images) {
    this.context = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    allImages = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

    imageView.setImageResource(allImages[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    View view = (View) object;

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);



    BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();


    if (bmpDrawable != null && bmpDrawable.getBitmap() != null && !bmpDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
        bmpDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

    container.removeView(view);
}
```

}

Если убрать этот код:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);



    BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();


    if (bmpDrawable != null && bmpDrawable.getBitmap() != null && !bmpDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
        bmpDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

то приложение будет нормально работать, однако на некоторых устройствах, и судя по статистике, в большей мере на самсунгах

[image: Статистика сбоев приложения]

будет выдавать такую ошибку:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  в строке:

```
  imageView.setImageResource(allImages[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для тяжелых, больших картинок я использую `Picasso`, потому что одним лишь `setImageResource` сыт не будешь. Я сам с этим сталкивался и теперь этим методом пользуюсь только с маленькими иконками.

Вообщем, используйте [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.a).into(imageView);
```

А этот код уберите

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
if (bmpDrawable != null && bmpDrawable.getBitmap() != null && !bmpDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
    bmpDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
}
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Это уже будет лишнее.